# Как распарсить json в php?

Tags: php, json

В json приходят два типа данных, такие:

```
"urls": {
        "0": "12.01.2021 16:16:19",
        "2": "12.01.2021 16:16:38",
        },
```

И такие:

```
"urls": [
        "12.01.2021 09:20:34"
    ],
```

Пытаюсь записать их в бд вот так: `bindParam(22, $row['urls'][0]);` Но записывается только такой вид, как снизу. Как записывать оба вида?

Comment: `json_decode($json_str, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб распарить json в php нужно использовать функцию `json_decode( $json, true )`. Второй параметр отвечает за вид json обьектов, когда параметр установлен в true данные будут возвращены ассоциативным массивом, когда параметр false json обьекты будут возвращены как объекты php
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

```
$json_example_1 = json_decode('{"urls":{"0":"12.01.2021 16:16:19","2":"12.01.2021 16:16:38"}}', true );
```

на выходе у вас получится массив такого вида в первом случае

```
Array
(
    [urls] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.01.2021 16:16:19
            [2] => 12.01.2021 16:16:38
        )

)

$json_example_2 = json_decode('{"urls":["12.01.2021 09:20:34"]}', true );
```

и массив такого вида во втором случае

```
Array
(
    [urls] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.01.2021 09:20:34
        )

)
```

Comment: Да, все работает, юзаю `$data = json_decode( $rawdata , true );` Все остальные данные записываются норм, а именно urls приходит иногда в первом виде, иногда во втором виде

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Вы хотите записать в бд все параметры из первого варианта?

Comment: Я хочу всегда записывать и из первого варианта, и из второго варианта

Comment: У вас записывается и первый и второй вариант, разница лишь в том что с таким вызовов bindParam вы всегда записываете первый элемент в массиве. Поэтому вам нужно определится как вы хотите записывать данные в бд, для каждого элемента новую строку или все элементы в одну ячейку. Если все элементы а одну ячейку то вы можете сохранить в базу json строку со всеми ссылками либо сериализировпнный массив со всеми ссылками и потом при получение данных из бд вы сможете распарить данные и вставить их в нужном вам виде

Comment: А как, например, сериализованный массив с ссылками и распарсенными данными вставить? Сори, если напрягаю, новиоп)

Comment: после того как вы распарсите json вы можете сохранять ссылки например вот так  bindParam(22, serialize( $row['urls'] ) ) ну и соответсвенно когда получите данные из бд и будете с ними работать вы можете сделать обратное преобразование через unserialize()